# Laravel + Docker error 139 while building php

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Helle everyone.

I've a little issue with Docker.
I try to create a basic docker-composer.yml for my projects with Laravel.

So here is my docker-compose.yml which is in the root directory of my project :

```html
version: '2'
services:
    php:
        container_name: php
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - cache
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3306"
            - "DB_HOST=mysql"
            - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
            - "REDIS_HOST=redis"
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/web.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "9000:9000"
        links:
            - php
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7.18
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=docker"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: redis:3.0
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
    cache:
        container_name: memcached
        image: memcached:alpine
        ports:
            - "11211:11211"
```

So as you can see, I try to install several containers : PHP, Nginx, MySql, Redis and Memcached.

Now here is my docker file for my PHP container :

```html
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

It's the code I've found on the docker website.

But the docker-compose up command start well and crash while executing the configuration file.

It returns

```
Step 1/2 : FROM php:7.0-fpm
 ---> e04605d12f83
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmcrypt-dev         libpng-dev     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
 ---> Running in fd19753fb969
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmcrypt-dev         libpng-dev     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd' 
returned a non-zero code: 139
```

Does anybody already has this kind of error ? I've tried with PHP 7.1 fpm, same error is triggered.

I don't see what is wrong.

Do not hesitate to ask me some other parts of code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your PHP configuration and it did not give me any problem when compiling the image

As an alternative:
[Try:](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/225#issuecomment-226870896)

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache freetype libpng libjpeg-turbo freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev && \
  docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
  NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) && \
  docker-php-ext-install -j${NPROC} gd && \
  apk del --no-cache freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply nasatome !

Whit your configuration, it seems to be good ! I have a successful message.

Where did you get this configuration ? Docker (and adminsys) is new for me, so I don't understand everything.

The 2 configurations are very different.

Now I have an error with mysql, but it seems to be a port issue.

Thank you again for you help :).

Comment: Take it out here: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/225#issuecomment-226870896

it is strange that the first configuration will not work ... sometimes they can be network problems, towards the ubuntu / debian servers, this other configuration is "alpine linux"

Comment: Worked for me, weird, i thought gd must be installed first, only then configured. How does it actually work?